# How to incorporate colSums for both vector and data frame in lappy

Tags: r

```
H_D<-function(level, zero, ...){
  special<-c(0,0,0)
  D<-list(special,...)
  
  cell <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(level, seq))    # create all cell
  support <- apply(cell, 1, function(x) +(x != zero)) # create all support set
  
  # provide subset H_D  (support sets and given vectors matches
  
  hd<-lapply(D, function (x)   cell[colSums(support==x)==length(x),]) 
  h_D<-do.call(rbind, hd)
  rownames(h_D)<-1:nrow(h_D)
  return(h_D)
}


level<-c(3,2,4)
zero<-c(1,2,1)
y<-c(0,1,1)
H_D(level,zero,y)

> H_D(level,zero,y)
Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    2    1
2    1    1    2
3    1    1    3
4    1    1    4
```

My function works fine for the above situation as colSums works for data frame. But if my argument is a vector instead of data frame this is not working. I am getting the following errors. My input argument could a vector or a data frame. How can I incorporate both in my above mention function?

```
level = 3
zero = 2
y<-1

H_D(level,zero,y)
> H_D(level,zero,y)
Error in colSums(support == x) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

I tried **drop=FALSE**, but not working!

Comment: The issue is that the `cell` created is a single column with `expand.grid`.  In that case, you can skip the rest of the computations i.e. `subset(do.call(expand.grid, lapply(3, seq)), Var1 != 2)`

Answer (score 0):

We could change the function with an `if/else` based on the number of columns of 'cell'.  If it is one column, then just do the `subset` or else do the other part of computation

```
H_D <- function(level, zero, ...){
  special <- c(0,0,0)
  D <- list(special,...)
  
  cell <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(level, seq))    # create all cell
 if(ncol(cell) == 1) {
     h_D <-   subset(cell, Var1 != zero) 
     
  } else {
  
    support <- apply(cell, 1, function(x) +(x != zero)) # create all support set
  
     # provide subset H_D  (support sets and given vectors matches
  
     hd <- lapply(D, function (x)   cell[colSums(support==x)==length(x),]) 
     h_D <- do.call(rbind, hd)
     rownames(h_D) <- 1:nrow(h_D)
  
}

return(h_D)
}
```

-testing

```
level <- 3
zero <- 2
y <- 1
 
H_D(level, zero, y)
#  Var1
#1    1
#3    3
```

and the first case

```
level <- c(3,2,4)
zero <- c(1,2,1)
y <- c(0,1,1)
H_D(level,zero,y)
# Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    1    2    1
#2    1    1    2
#3    1    1    3
#4    1    1    4
```